# Is TestNG not compatible with Eclipse Neon?

Tags: eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

I've got a new machine at work, finally! I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it and then installed Java 1.8 and Eclipse Neon. This seemed fine. I then went to the Eclipse Marketplace and installed TestNG. Whilst it looks like this has installed I can't seem to see any TestNG options in the menus. As an example I should be able to do File->New->Other->TestNG, etc. but there is nothing there.

Can I get this working, or will I have to uninstall Neon and switch back to Mars?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, try restarting the eclipse and then try again.

Comment: TestNG eclipse plugin works fine on Eclipse Neon, if you still encounter issue on Neon (assume you had restarted eclipse after installed the plugin as @selva suggested), there should be something in the error log view: click 'Window' on the top level menu -> show view -> error log, please paste the relate error that can help diagnose the issue if there's any:)

Answer (score 0):

It's working like a charm for me on a fresh install of Neon + TestNG plugin only.

Maybe you have an issue between 2 plugins.

Retry to install Neon + TestNG, it is supposed to work.